# Datatables : How to render <a> html tag?

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatables

Here is my datatables init.

```
var dataTable = $('#categoriesTable').dataTable(
    {
    "pageLength": 5,
    "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, 100], [5, 10, 25, 50, 100]],


    "ajax": {
        url: "http://mata.mu/coeg_cms/sempak/posts/categories",
        type: "GET"
    },
    "bSort": false,
    "columns" : [
        { "data": "name"},
        { "data": "slug"},
        { "data": "term_taxonomy.description"},
        { "data": "term_id", "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
                var delete_url = '<a href="'+$(location).attr('href')+'/'+data+'" class="button small alert expand" data-method="delete" data-reveal-id="myModal'+data+'" data-name="'+name+'">Delete</a>';
                return delete_url;
            }
        }
    ],


    "responsive" : true
});
```

yes the above code will generate table then add column for action delete

```
<a href="http://mata.mu/coeg_cms/sempak/posts/categories/71" class="button small alert expand" data-method="delete" data-reveal-id="myModal71" data-name="">Delete</a>
```

why `data-name` attribute is blank ? it should show name from first column ? how to do that ? please correct my render function

Comment: `name` isn't defined. You can use `data`, `type`, `full` and `meta` in your function.

Comment: @StephanVierkant , sorry i am new, then how to show name ? maybe you can give referention link,

if i use `function(data, type, full, meta, name)` data-name will be `data-name=undefined`

Comment: Can you add an example of what your data looks like to the question?

Comment: Use `console.log(full)` to see which parameters you can use. I'm not sure, but maybe you can use `full.name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` variable is not defined. You need to get the value of it using the `full` argument that you are passing to your function.

The `full` variable represents the data for the entire row. So you can use that to access the `name` for that row.

You can probably just do `full.name` to get the name.